# How to remember which network connection to use?

Tags: network-manager

I have two connections: universal using DHCP and static IP for my home network. I'm usualy at home, so I want to use my static home connection. But every reboot, it's connected using DHCP and I have to change it manualy. So, how can I make network manager to use my home connection first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click on network indicator → Edit connections...
2. Choose DHCP connection `Auto` or whatever its named → Edit → General tab
3. Uncheck *Automatically connect to this network when it is available*

So it will always reconnect to the other connection (static).